# protobuf-c building on Cygwin

Tags: c, arm, protocol-buffers

I have successfully built the protobuf-c on Cygwin (Windows 10) and I am now trying to cross compile the libprotobuf-c.a for ARM Cortex but I keep running into issues with config trying to test building executables on Cygwin and failing.  See below.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the config command and its output:

```plaintext
$ ./configure --disable-protoc  --disable-dependency-tracking --host=arm-none-eabi --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin CFLAGS="-IC:/NXP/S32DS.3.2/S32DS/build_tools/gcc_b1620/arm32_ewl2/EWL_C/include -D__FPU_PRESENT=1 -DARMCM7_SP=1 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mcpu=cortex-m7 -specs=C:/NXP/S32DS.3.2/S32DS/build_tools/gcc_b1620/arm32_ewl2/lib/ewl_c9x_noio.specs" LDFLAGS="-nostartfiles -L/lib/thumb/v7-m -Xlinker --gc-sections -n -lgcc"
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-none-eabi-strip... arm-none-eabi-strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... arm-none-eabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/protobuf-c-master-arm/protobuf-c-master':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Here is a grep "error" output of the config.log file

```plaintext
$ grep error config.log
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
configure:3644: error: in `/protobuf-c-master-arm/protobuf-c-master':
configure:3646: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

There are no instructions on the protobuf-c site for cross compiling besides some general hints.  The CFLAGS and LDFLAGS options to the config command come from our own makefile we use to build our application.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste text (like commands and output) to your question as text instead of showing a screenshot. If you followed some instructions for cross-compiling, please provide a link to the instructions.

Comment: We cannot copy/paste any command/command output because you provided an image instead of copying/pasting the text displayed in your window. This is not helping people who may want to help. What is the version of Windows you are using ?

Comment: Sorry, I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Alternatives would be to use protobuf-c, nanopb or protobuf-embedded-c - see [this benchmark](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/benchmark).

Comment: @Frant Unfortunately my benchmark is terribly outdated; I added a notice to it now. Since then I've managed to bloat nanopb, protobuf-embedded-c has been unmaintained for years, and some new libraries have popped up (listed in bottom of https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/ )

Comment: Thanks for all the information @Frant  
I am a little unclear about your suggestion to use protobuf-c, I thought that was what I was using. I was trying to use the hints from the Wiki for protobuf-c regarding building for embedded systems at 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-c/wikis/Examples.wikiProtobuf-C

Comment: @Paul Art: I am the one who was unclear, I did download Google protocol buffer by reflex, my bad. Suggestion: next time, just use an hyperlink to the source code, i.e. [protobuf-c](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-c/source/default/source) instead of `protobuf-c`, this does remove the need for people to look for the exact code you were trying to compile by themselves.

Comment: @jpa: thank you for the additional information.

Comment: If I use nanopb I don't need to build anything?  Just include generated headers and .c in my normal build?